# How to create a suggestion popup in JavaScript similar to what online text editors do

Tags: javascript, popup, editor, autosuggest

I am trying to create a text suggestion popup in JavaScript without external libraries, similar to what online text editors or code playgrounds do (for example the TypeScript Playground - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play).

[image: TypeScript Playground on the browser]

The popup box should be displayed next to the word you are typing and contain the list of suggested words that you can select through the up/down arrows and return (or tab) combination.

So mainly I haven't figured out:

1. how to render the popup box next to the word you are typing and how the popup is always aligned with the last character
2. how the word you select from the popup will replace the one you are typing

Comment: why don't you try creating a dictionary type object where when the user writes something the program checks the word or letters are matching any existing entries or not. This is my concept so far even though i can already tell that at first it won't cause any problems but the more entries you put in the object it would take so long to execute literally taking more ram and cpu.

Comment: Thanks @AniketLodh but I am thinking more about the UI, essentially how to render a popup box next to the word you are typing with a list of suggestions, and once one is selected it will replace the word you are typing.

Comment: Are you intending to use a standard Textarea element, or something else?

Comment: Yes I am thinking about a textarea element or alternatively an editable div.